# How will the current flow in the figure drawn below?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, conductors

[image: figure]

Consider the green material in the figure to be conducting. So, I was wondering how the current will flow in the rod, as the battery is not connected at the ends, but on the surface of the rod. Thus, will there be no current at the ends of the rod and what about voltage?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

An approximate numerically calculated figure is attached.
The figure is a two-dimensional result.
Although 3D calculations is possible, the figure is easier to see in 2D.
$\phi$ is potential in volts.
$\vec{J}$ is the electric current density.
[image]

(Edit #1)
I add a figure highlighting the elements in the two left-most columns.
[image]

Comment: In the figure I can see small Current Density(J) so does it mean that feasible current will be there ?

Comment: Excellent answer! It is interesting how far the current goes. There is definitely current further away from the contact point than I thought there would be

Comment: This trips up people with ground/power plane design too. People tend to be surprised by how much a heavy load can affect voltages elsewhere on the plane, even on points 'the other side' of the main connection. It would be interesting to redo this with deep slots (cut away the 6th-and-10th set from the left of rectangles, except for the top one) cut from the bottom.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you simulate this?

Comment: @TLW, the "cut from the bottom" calculation itself is simple and easy, but it takes time and effort to write a report that accurately captures the new results. That is why it cannot be done here.

Comment: @Landak, I performed this calculation with a finite element (FE) code of my own development and plotting is performed by the GiD pre/post processor. My code is still incomplete; having bugs and documents is in short. Of the many types of electromagnetic FE calculations, this calculation is one of the easier ones, solving Laplace's equation with fixed potentials at two points. For example, if you have access to a finite element code that can solve temperature calculations, you should be able to perform similar calculation with that code.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. There won't be any noticeable amount current at the ends of the rod because the electric field formed inside the conductor will be restricted so the electrons will dominantly experience the force when they are in the region between the points across which the potential difference is applied or else there might be some small amount influence of electric field at the end and the area near the end, which will result in some negligible amount of current.

And the same thing goes with potential difference. The potential at one end and the point at which the wire is connected will be nearly same and hence the potential difference will be nearly equal to zero and you won't find any significant amount of current behind those two points at which the wires are connected.

While doing some **ideal** calculations you can also neglect the resistance of that region of the rod which is on the left of positive terminal and same with which is on the right of negative terminal to get some near to accurate results.

Comment: I don't understand your geometry.  "that region only across which the wires are connected"  Do you mean no current to the left of the conductor on the left?  "any current behind those two points"   do you mean, for example, to the left of the conductor on the left?

Comment: @garyp yes that's what I mean. In other words it can be said that the electrons will flow in the region across which the potential difference is applied by the battery. Except that region, you will approximately find that there is no current.

Comment: Ok, I wanted to clarify that because with that interpretation your answer is not correct as the other answers here show.

Comment: @garyp I want to know actually what's making my answer wrong I still didn't understand according to you what is wrong with my answer. Is it wrong or right? Still struggling to make my answer better.

Comment: @garyp I really want to know what actually you found wrong in this.

Comment: Look at the simulation result in the other answer. It shows that there **is** current at the end of the rod.

Comment: As evidenced by the other existing answer, this is simply wrong. Comments on that answer show it is a common misconception; the voltage does not simply disappear outside the line between the contacts, nor does current.

Comment: @Nij actually you can read out the second comment, I've written that you will approximately find that there is no current at the ends and the regions near that from the wire connected. But that seems partially incomplete not a completely wrong answer. I'll edit the answer for this so that people should not get confused, Thank you for pointing out this mistake.

Comment: @ThePhoton you can checkout the improvements I've made in my post. Does that edit makes you to understand better? Or else you can again notify me so that i can delete or re-edit my answer.

Comment: The edit improves the answer, but I still object to a few things.  Whether or not the current is noticeible depends the sensitivity of the detector.  The word *negligible*.: negligible is in the eye of the beholder.   That is, whether or not the current is negligible depends on what you want to know about the system.   The same applies to whether or not you neglect the resistance in the regions "outside" of the wires.